# External transaction manager for Activiti

Tags: hibernate, transactions, activiti

I'm using Spring+Hibernate. And I've just started to use Acitiviti framework (which use MyBatis).

How can I use common transaction for Hibernate & Activiti with Spring?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

applicationContext.xml

```
 <!-- common transaction manager -->
    <bean id="transactionManager" 
       class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager">
      <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory"/>
    </bean>

    <!-- activiti processEngineConfiguration -->
    <bean id="processEngineConfiguration" class="org.activiti.spring.SpringProcessEngineConfiguration">
    ............................        
     <property name="transactionManager" ref="transactionManager" />
    ...........................
    </bean>
```

Comment: Thanks for reply! Very important question for me: can I organize session-per-conversation with common transaction for Hibernate & Activiti??

Comment: I mean does it possible to use extended conversation with session.setFlushMode(FlushMode.MANUAL)?

Comment: When you pass an external transaction manager, activiti never tries to manage a transaction itself, it leaves all that to the transaction manager. So if you implement session-per-conversation pattern activiti and hibernate will use same transaction